# Angular 14 Form Control - Inheriting recursively types from interface

Tags: angular-forms, angular14

I was wondering if anyone managed use complex interfaces to take advantage of the new typed FormControl and avoid boilerplate code on components.

I manage to export a 1-level-only interface with:

```
interface ISimple {
 a: number; b: string; c: Date
}
export type AsFormControls<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: FormControl<T[K]>;
}
```

and then declaring my form in my component as

```
form: FormGroup<AsFormControls<ISimple>>;
```

Some of my simple forms were just plug and play, very useful, but when I have something like the following I can't figure out how to proceed, because I need the a FormGroup type for properties that contain properties.

```
interface INotSoSimple {
 d: {
   e: string; 
   f: Date;
 }
}
```

Could there be a way to modify this interface for it to work with the new Form Controls? Any leads?